# Listen For MetaData Changes in Firebase Firestore database

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am creating a chat module using Firestore database. Following is my listener code that listen for new messages in:

```
   mDb.collection("Users_Collection").document(mAuth.getUid()).collection("Recipients")
                .document(psychichObj.getUid()).collection("Messages").orderBy("time").limit(30)
                .addSnapshotListener(MetadataChanges.INCLUDE, new EventListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onEvent(@Nullable QuerySnapshot queryDocumentSnapshots, @Nullable FirebaseFirestoreException e) {
                        if (e==null){
                            for (DocumentChange dc:queryDocumentSnapshots.getDocumentChanges()){
                                switch (dc.getType()){
                                    case ADDED:
                                        Log.d("chatevents", "onEvent:Added ");
                                        messgaesDataClass msg = dc.getDocument().toObject(messgaesDataClass.class);
                                        messages.add(msg);
                                        chatAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                                        messagesRecycler.smoothScrollToPosition(messages.size());
                                        break;
                                    case REMOVED:
                                        Log.d("chatevents", "onEvent:Removed ");

                                    case MODIFIED:
                                        Log.d("chatevents", "onEvent:Modiefied ");

                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                });
```

When I send a message than I want to know how can I listen for a msg object that is in local cache or whose metadata is in pending state and not sent to the server yet?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When passing a [MetadataChanges](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/firestore/MetadataChanges) to the Query's [addSnapshotListener(MetadataChanges metadataChanges, EventListener listener)](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/firestore/Query.html#addSnapshotListener(com.google.firebase.firestore.MetadataChanges,%20com.google.firebase.firestore.EventListener%3Ccom.google.firebase.firestore.QuerySnapshot%3E)) method:

> Indicates whether metadata-only changes (i.e. only Query.getMetadata() changed) should trigger snapshot events.

Which basically means that every time the metadata changes, the listener is triggered. So in case of pending operations, the value of the variable `pending` will be changed.

> I want to know how can i listen for a msg object that is in local cache

In this case, you should consider using SnapshotMetadata's [isFromCache()](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/firebase/firestore/SnapshotMetadata.html#isFromCache()) method:

```
Log.d(TAG, "isFromCache: " + documentSnapshot.getMetadata().isFromCache());
```

When I'm online it prints:

```
isFromCache: false
```

When I'm offline, it prints:

```
isFromCache: true
```

Comment: ok so when i send a message and its not sent to the server yet than the listeners document.Added case will run in my switch statement with a pending tag , right ? so when i am online and its sent to the server than would document.Added case would run again  or document.Modified case would run ?

Comment: No, `onEvent:Added` will be printed once for every item that correspond to your query and second, for every new item that is added at that particular location with the `MetadataChanges` that correspond in that particular moment. If you want to know when the data is commited on Firebase servers, you need to use a `CompleteListener`.

Comment: If there is a loss of network connectivity (there is no network connection on user device), neither onSuccess() nor onComplete() are triggered. This behavior makes sense, since the task is only considered completed when the data has been committed (or rejected) on the Firebase servers. Is it ok now?